# Is there any way to represent connections between json objects with a graph?

Tags: java, json, swing, graph, dot

I have a java program and i am parsing a json file. Because there are some dependencies between the json objects (they are procedures that must be executed so some of them depends on others). I want to make a graph so i can represent this. Is there any known way? I tryed mxgraph (jgraph) but i cannot make the representation.

Here is a simple json format

```
 {
  "blueprint": 
    {
     "1" : { "depends" : null },
     "2" : { "depends" : "1" },
     "3" : { "depends" : { "2" , "1"} },
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can take a look at https://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: I think that for graphviz you need it to be installed, right? I found a java class for graphiz but i think it is only a wrapper of the application.

Comment: Yes. And you will have to add it to your PATH.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you got any example? There isnt any other way right?

Comment: I am not aware if there is another way or not. I am just aware that Graphviz could work in the thing you ask. About examples, a simple google search led me in this repo https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think that i will try it with graphviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this old question of mine just in case somebody needs it.

graphviz.org with dot language was the way I tackled it.

Thank you everyone for the comments.